# Sphinx - API returned results appear to ignore title column

Tags: php, sphinx

I've setup the latest version of Sphinx and I'm using the PHP API.

Currently the returned results from the API seem to be radically different from the search daemon results. It appears the API results are completely ignoring the title column in the database. As a consequence the 'in page' results are nonsensical as, even though the search query contains key words that appear in the titles, the results don't display the documents with matching titles (they're buried somewhere in the middle of the 1000+ results).

Below is the sphinx config & the PHP script that interacts with the API.

http://pastebin.com/mLmawDh9

```
    // PHP script
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->SetServer($CONF['sphinx_host'], $CONF['sphinx_port']);
    $cl->SetFieldWeights(array("title"=>10));
    $cl->SetLimits(0, 1000);
    $result = $cl->Query($q);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sphinx PHP API order differs from Search Daemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162698/sphinx-php-api-order-differs-from-search-daemon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have made some progress - please ignore this question the following has the upto-date response with this query
[Sphinx PHP API order differs from Search Daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162698/sphinx-php-api-order-differs-from-search-daemon)