# Sphinx PHP API order differs from Search Daemon

Tags: php, sphinx

I've setup Sphinx and having an issue with the PHP API ordering returning - the search daemon returns the correct array response however the PHP API seems to returns in ID order. 
Does anyone have any idea why it is doing the following..

UPDATE: I've noticed the problem seems to occur with single word searches.. eg if I entered 'guide to dyspraxia' the result from the PHP API looks fine - any ideas why?

```
// running via SSH using the 'search dyspraxia' (search daemon command)
displaying matches:
1. document=5994, weight=2846, title=A guide to dyspraxia, table_id=3
2. document=3993, weight=1731, title=THE WRITE THING FOR BOYS, table_id=3
3. document=2697, weight=1668, title=SEN And Sensibility, table_id=3
4. document=3320, weight=1668, title=SEN And Sensibility, table_id=3
5. document=3810, weight=1668, title=SEN support in schools  in or out of the classroom?, table_id=3
6. document=4304, weight=1668, title=The Ukulele Strategy, table_id=3
7. document=4437, weight=1668, title=Let the future in, table_id=3
8. document=5273, weight=1668, title=Working memory is the key to learning, table_id=3
9. document=5396, weight=1668, title=Mind mapping for dyslexics, table_id=3

words:
1. 'dyspraxia': 9 documents, 27 hits

// PHP API script 
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer($CONF['sphinx_host'], $CONF['sphinx_port']);
$cl->SetLimits(0, 1000);
$result = $cl->Query($q);

// returned $result['matches'] below note 2697 is first, where-as in the search daemon the first document id is 5994

Array ( 
[2697] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[3320] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[3810] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[3993] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[4304] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[4437] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[5273] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[5396] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) 
[5994] => Array ( [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [table_id] => 3 ) ) )
```

Comment: Just a point of clarification, 'search' is NOT a daemon. It directly opens the index files and runs a search there an then. It does not stay loaded. Like mentioned in the other answer, best not to rely on it. On the other hand searchd is a daemon - and is what you should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like search tool defaults to bm25 ranking . Try adding 
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
$cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_BM25);
You should get same result.
Btw, don't trust search tool too much , it's more for testing and kinda a 'second class citizen' in the Sphinx project. Use API or sql interface.