# Sphinx - Using multiple sql_attr_uint in configuration

Tags: php, api, full-text-search, sphinx

I need to use two sql_attr_uint values per index in my config file. I've found out from a previous post not to put too much faith in the search command via the command-line.
[Sphinx PHP API order differs from Search Daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162698/sphinx-php-api-order-differs-from-search-daemon)

My current issue is I am uable to retrieve both of the sql_attr_uint values when being accessed by the PHP API (however both sql_attr_uint values appear when using search via the command line)

Below is my config file..
http://pastebin.com/30Si7bw5

When getting the the results via the PHP API I can only see the sql_attr_uint table_id, but not the sql_attr_uint called pub_id.

Can anyone suggest why it would do this?

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer($CONF['sphinx_host'], $CONF['sphinx_port']);
$cl->SetMatchMode($mode);
$cl->SetLimits(0, 1000);
// below line commented out atm - to only show those rows with this sql_attr_uint of 760 (is this the correct syntax?)
//$cl->SetFilter ( 'pub_id', array(760), FALSE );
$result = $cl->Query($q);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you are not restarting searchd propelly. You still have using an old index.

When you reindex, make sure you use --rotate, to cause searchd to reload.

failing that. stop searchd completely, reindex the index and initiate a clean startup.

(your syntax is correct, something else going on)

Comment: thanks!! the --rotate worked, i was doing it manually (deleting the data folder, doing indexer --all etc)

Comment: ah great. --rotate is the definitly the best way. Its ideal for using in a crontab to periodically reindex. It initiates a nice clean reload, that shouldnt interupt a live serving daemon.